# How to return values of only one parameter in GetMapping?

Tags: java, spring, api

I have an API. How to return the values of only one column (name) from the database? Request code in the controller:

```
@RestController
public class PURController {
    @Autowired
    private PURRepository purRepository;
@CrossOrigin()
    @GetMapping("/purs/getname/{device}")
    public ResponseEntity<ArrayList<PUR>> getPurName(@PathVariable(value = "device") String device){
         ArrayList<PUR> pur = purRepository.findAllByDevice(device);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(pur);
    }
```

In this case, all rows found by the "device" field are returned. Also I have a method in PUR.java:

```
public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

How can it all be connected?

Also: my repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface PURRepository extends JpaRepository<PUR, Long> {
    ArrayList<PUR> findAllByDevice(String device);
    Optional<PUR> findByDevice(String device);}
```

Response now:

```
[{"id":48,"name":"6-PRN.00-00.01","quantity":3,"device":"6-PRN.01-01.000"},{"id":49,"name":"6-PRN.00-00.02","quantity":7,"device":"6-PRN.01-01.000"},{"id":50,"name":"6-PRN.00-00.03","quantity":4,"device":"6-PRN.01-01.000"}]
```

Response i want:

```
[{6-PRN.00-00.01},{6-PRN.00-00.02},{6-PRN.00-00.03}]
```

Comment: Can the `6-PRN.00-00.01` be wrapped in double quotes?

Comment: @dan1st, I think so

Comment: That's not valid JSON, so it's not a response you can get. You can get `[{"name":"6-PRN.00-00.01"}]`, or you can get `["6-PRN.00-00-01"]`, but you can not get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use stream. You can solve it easily:

```
  @Query(value = "SELECT p.name FROM PUR p where p.device= :device", nativeQuery = true)
  List<String> findAllNamesByDevice(@Param("device") String device);
```

Comment: This works, but it returns absolutely all the values from the table. There is no selection by the "device" parameter

Comment: sorry i forget to where clause, I updated check it again please

Answer (score 2):

You can stream the list you have and only keep the `pur.name` Strings:

```
ArrayList<PUR> pur = purRepository.findAllByDevice(device);
List<String> purNames = pur.stream.map(p -> p.getName()).toList();
return ResponseEntity.ok().body(purNames);
```

edited: the other answers are also right, `purRepository.findAllDeviceNames` will be more effective because you'll retrieve less data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting extra load on your database and returning the entire record and possible joined/referenced objects, add a dedicated query that returns just the name.

```
@Repository
public interface PURRepository extends JpaRepository<PUR, Long> {
    @Query("select p.name from PUR p where PUR.deviceId == ?1")
    ArrayList<String> findAllDeviceNames(String device);
```

Then:

```
public ResponseEntity<ArrayList<PUR>> getPurName(@PathVariable(value = "device") String device){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(purRepository.findAllDeviceNames(device));
}
```